# SQL Injection, how can I SQL inject into this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, code-injection

So I am basically learning SQL injection because I want to be a pen tester.  Here is an example of a query I'm running on localhost/phpmyadmin

```
SELECT *
FROM ipstealer as ipstr
WHERE 'id' = 9
union select 1,2,3,4,5
ORDER BY
ipstr.id ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Where I can inject after WHERE ID = $inputhere

So basically, the query works fine if I do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ipstealer
WHERE 'id' = 9
union select 1,2,3,4,5
ORDER BY
id ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But I want to inject it using aliases ipstr.  So my question is, how can I fix this problem with the injection so that it works as wanted in the first query?  I can't figure out how to do this only using one query.  I've logically tried something like so:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM ipstealer as ipstr
    WHERE 'id' = 9
    union select 1,2,3,4,5 as ipstr
    ORDER BY
    ipstr.id ASC
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But I get the same error: #1054 - Unknown column 'ipstr.id' in 'order clause'

Comment: to know more about sql injection, visi this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php